# BigQuery skip, take for data grid paging

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to skip records, take a certain amount of records and get the total number of records for my data grid using BigQuery. I know how to take records (the page size):

```
   SELECT * FROM `my_table` where name='sonic' LIMIT 10
```

Now I need to skip "x" amount of records based on what page the user is on. I can this data, I just dont know the big query syntax to do it. Sql Server does it this way

```
   SELECT col1, col2, ...
   FROM ...
   WHERE ... 
   ORDER BY -- this is a MUST there must be ORDER BY statement
    -- the paging comes here
   OFFSET     10 ROWS       -- skip 10 rows
```

I also need the total number of records for the query to display a total records count.

How do I do this using big query? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BigQuery Standard SQL you can use below syntax

```
LIMIT count [ OFFSET skip_rows ]
```

LIMIT specifies a non-negative count of type INT64, and no more than count rows will be returned. LIMIT 0 returns 0 rows.

If there is a set operation, LIMIT is applied after the set operation is evaluated.

OFFSET specifies a non-negative number of rows to skip before applying LIMIT. skip_rows is of type INT64.

These clauses accept only literal or parameter values. The rows that are returned by LIMIT and OFFSET are unspecified unless these operators are used after ORDER BY.

You can see more about [LIMIT clause and OFFSET clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#limit_clause_and_offset_clause)